# Scikit-Learn: How to deal with an unorderable types error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder, python-3.5

I'm working on Python 3.5 to predict some data in test.csv based on data in train.csv. 
While performing data munging, I convert the rows and columns of train.csv which works perfectly fine. But when doing the same with test.csv, it's giving a :
TypeError : unorderable types: float() > str()

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header = 0, parse_dates = True, low_memory= False)
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv' , header =0, parse_dates = True, low_memory= False)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

train.Category = le.fit_transform(train.Category)
train.DayOfWeek = le.fit_transform(train.DayOfWeek)
train.PdDistrict = le.fit_transform(train.PdDistrict)
```

Error part

```
test.DayOfWeek = le.fit_transform(test.DayOfWeek)
test.PdDistrict = le.fit_transform(test.PdDistrict)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems. You should not be reusing the same `LabelEncoder` for multiple columns. Otherwise you will lose the mapping and not be able to transform your test data.

```
category_le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
day_of_week_le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
pd_district_le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

train_category = category_le.fit_transform(train.Category)
train_day_of_week = day_of_week_le.fit_transform(train.DayOfWeek)
train_pd_district = pd_district_le.fit_transform(train.PdDistrict)

train_X = np.hstack([train_category_mat, train_day_of_week_mat, pd_district_le])

test_category = category_le.transform(test.Category)
test_day_of_week = day_of_week_le.transform(test.DayOfWeek)
test_pd_district = pd_district_le.transform(test.PdDistrict)
```

Comment: I've tried this and it returns the same TypeError :(

Comment: Are all columns string? If not should use one hot encoder instead.

Comment: Yes. I've compared dtypes for train.csv with test.csv and they both are the same

Comment: But are they string? LabelEncoder only works for string I believe

Comment: It shows as an object even if I try to change it to string type

Comment: pandas treats string as dtype object. Is it possible the test dataframe has different types than the train dataframe?

Comment: could you add the output of `train.head()`, `test.head()`, `train.dtypes` and `test.dtypes` to your question?

Comment: I figured out the issue. I recasted the fields I wanted to work with LE to string type and then it works fine :)

Comment: Excellent. Also realized I previously assumed you were using label binarizer. You probably want to use it instead.

Comment: I'm working with multi class data, so I overlooked binarizer. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a quick code snippet to help with the unorderable type error, for anyone else who is searching.

The issue (which you've already found) is pasted here, as found in another forum post: "because there were essentially mixed types within the column I was trying to encode. I was finally able to get around it by **converting each of the 'object' type columns to 'str' type and that stopped the error**."

After dealing with missing data, this code can be used to iterate through columns matching a set of datatypes and convert them to string, using  the `.astype(str)` property.

```
#REPLACE NAN WITH 0
X_train.fillna(0.0, inplace=True)

#GET LIST OF COLUMNS TO ENCODE
cols_to_enc = list(X_train.select_dtypes(include=['category', 'object']))

for feature in cols_to_enc:
    try:
        #CONVERT VALUE TO STRING (TO AVOID UNORDERED TYPE ERRORS)
        X_train[feature] = X_train[feature].astype(str)
    except Exception as err:
        print('cannot convert: %s' %  feature)
        print(err)
```